# Estimate Imagesize of any given Particular Control object?

Tags: image, gui-construction

I make different controls(InputFields,Text,panel, etc) in my code for which the corresponding code is below.

```
  inputFieldValue = 10;
  (*Markers*)
  markers = Row[{
                Column[{
                MouseAppearance[
                               Style["\[FilledUpTriangle]", Bold, Black, {15,15},ShowStringCharacters -> False],
                                "LinkHand"
                                ],
                MouseAppearance[
                                Style["\[FilledDownTriangle]", Bold, Black, {15, 15}, ShowStringCharacters -> False],
                                "LinkHand"
                              ]
                       },
                      Spacings -> 0,
                      Alignment -> Center,
                      Background -> RGBColor[0.65, 0.65, 0.65]
                     ](*Column is CLosed*)
                },
               BaselinePosition -> Axis
              ];
   (*InputField*)
   field = Dynamic[Row[{InputField[
                            Dynamic[inputFieldValue],
                            Number,
                            ContinuousAction -> True,
                            ImageSize -> {50, 20},
                            Alignment -> Center
                                 ]
                        },
                        BaselinePosition -> Axis
                      ]
                   ];
```

I want to find exact `ImageSizes` of the controls for accurate placement in another grid. I am listing the options that I have with me here.

case1:

```
     Rasterize[markers][[2, 2]]
```

case2:

```
    Rasterize[field][[2, 2]]
```

and also,I arrange this controls in different formats.like,

arrange1:

```
 userField = Row[{
            markers,
            field
            },
        Frame -> False
        ]
```

arrange2:

```
     panelRow = 
            Panel[Row[{userField, userField, userField, userField, userField, 
                  userField, userField, userField, userField, userField
                     }], 
                  FrameMargins -> -3, Appearance -> "Frameless"
                 ]
```

case3:

```
 Rasterize[userField][[2, 2]]
```

case4:

```
Rasterize[panelRow][[2, 2]]
```

if you evaluate `case1`,the `ImageSize` is ({9,23}) which is wrong as I have already mentioned `size` of markers is `{15,15}`.

[Based on the options provided here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17887/how-to-find-image-size-of-a-control-object), I did try to use the `Rasterize` function with no success.
 My idea is to figure out the `Imagesize` and span them across a layout whose pixel or unit value is 10. Also, if I have an image of an odd dimension, for example, like `ImageSize -> {67, 38}, I want to set my values for the control object to next closest higher multiple of span value, which in the case of my example is {70, 40} so that my control object will not suffer due to insufficient spaces.

Yet another option that I did try was to use `Options[markers]` which also does not give me the value of the size of the control objects. Right now, I am putting my control objects into `Pane` with scroll bars to accommodate for different sizes of the control objects without compromising the size or display of the control objects.

Comment: There's also `Rasterize[a, "RasterSize"]` if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what you're trying to do here, but here's a simple observation on one of the things you're doing:

```
g = Rasterize[
  Style["\[FilledUpTriangle]", Bold, Black, {15, 15}, 
    ShowStringCharacters -> False]]
```

[image: triangle]

The [15,15} appears to be (mostly) ignored, because the resulting graphic is {9,16}.

Comment: ok fine,then How can we estimate the exact size of control objedts?

Comment: The {15,15} is in the wrong place: g = Rasterize[
  Style["\[FilledUpTriangle]", Bold, Black, 
   ShowStringCharacters -> False], RasterSize -> {15, 15}]
creates a {15,15} image as Szabolcs suggested.